# Python 3.8.1 Discord.py Rewrite Reactions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

I am currently in development of a custom discord bot for my server. I am (trying) creating a poll system. So the user does `-poll yn poll question`. the yn part describes the type of question such as yes/no. this is what I have so far:

```
@client.command()
async def poll(ctx, typee, *, msgg):
    if typee=='yn':
        msg = await ctx.channel.send("@everyone " + msgg)
        reactions = ['a']
        for emoji in reactions: 
            await client.add_reaction(msg, emoji)
        await ctx.message.delete()
```

when running this I get the error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'
```

I am using rewrite and python 3.8.1

Answer (score 3):

The `add_reaction` method is part of the message object and not the client object. What you need is `await msg.add_reaction(emoji)` instead of `await client.add_reaction(msg, emoji)`

Another thing in case you weren't aware `'a'` isn't a valid emoji.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do `await msg.add_reaction(emoji)` instead of `await client.add...` I believe.

I assume you're aware `"a"` isn't a valid emoji, you can find a dictionary of the names vs the unicode for them [here](https://gist.github.com/Vexs/629488c4bb4126ad2a9909309ed6bd71)

Also, perhaps best to avoid including an @everyone if this can be used by anyone! You can restrict it to people with certain permissions, or you yourself as the owner. You can do this with decorators, you can find a big list of these [here](https://gist.github.com/Painezor/eb2519022cd2c907b56624105f94b190).